# scipy linear spline fitting with predefined number of knots

Tags: scipy, curve-fitting, spline, linear-interpolation

I try to fit a n knot linear splines to a set of points. 
Now scipy have a method that fits polynomial of degree d (I set it to 1 for liner) to a set of points, but I cant define the number of knots I want (I can influence the number of knots via some constant parameter but I dont know it in advance, and search him with trail and error too expansive).
I found a method that fits a curve to a set of points, it looked very promising at first.

I tried to fit a linear spline with 3 knots, basicly the idea is to define a function that gets as parameter the location of the knots and the parameters of each line of the three.
unfortunately I think it doesn't converges.

I am looking for new Ideas on how to easily implement what I try to achieve.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def knot3_spline_wrapper(x,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4):
    vfunc = np.vectorize(knot3_spline)
    return vfunc(x,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4)

def knot3_spline(x,a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4):
    if x <c1:
        return x*a1+b1
    if c1<=x <c2:
        return x*a2+b2
    if c2<=x<c3:
        return x*a3+b3
    if c3<=x:
        return x*a4+b4
xdata = np.linspace(-2, 2, 50)
y = np.power(xdata, 2)
plt.plot(xdata, y, 'b-', label='data')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(knot3_spline_wrapper, xdata, y)
knot3_spline_wrapper(xdata, *popt)
plt.plot(xdata, knot3_spline_wrapper(xdata, *popt), 'r-')
```

EDIT: I want to mention, I don't know nor want to specify knot positions...
I want to find a way to find the "best" positions and the best lines that solve my problem

result: [image]

Answer (score 2):

With the scipy function [`LSQUnivariateSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline)  the position of wanted knots can be specified:

```
from scipy.interpolate import LSQUnivariateSpline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# Generate some data
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 123)
y = 3 + 10*x**2 + np.random.randn(len(x))

# Define wanted knot positions
knot_positions = np.linspace(-0.7, 0.7, 4)

# Performe the spline fitting (degree=k)
spline = LSQUnivariateSpline(x, y, knot_positions, k=1)

# Graph
y_fit = spline(x)

x_knots = spline.get_knots()
y_knots = spline(x_knots)

plt.plot(x, y, '.', color='black', label='data points');
plt.plot(x, y_fit, '-', color='red', label='fit');
plt.plot(x_knots, y_knots, 'o', color='red', label='knots')
plt.legend(); plt.xlabel('x'); plt.ylabel('y');
```

the graph is:

[image: linear spline fitting]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thenks but I don't know nor want to specify knot positions... I want to find a way to find the "best" positions and the best lines that solve my problem

Comment: @misha312 When the position of the knots is not known, there is one iterative method I am aware of, "Estimating regression models with unknown breakpoints" by Vito M. R. Muggeo. It works by iterating segmented linear regression, see an answer I wrote some time ago https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/32833/53362

Comment: note: There is a comment on the original question pointing to this library  https://pypi.org/project/pwlf/, which seems to use non linear optimiztion method to find best breaking points positions

Comment: great that was helpful but unfortunately this library works very slow (doesn't finish at all for more than 6 knots)